# What is the escape character for MsgBox in Access VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

In Access, you can display a formatted messagebox by using the following:

`Eval "MsgBox(""One@two@three"")"`

'One' will appear in bold, and 'two' and 'three' will appear on separate lines.  I want to display an email adddress, so I need to escape the @ symbol.  I've tried square brackets, backslash, backtick, double-@, with no luck.  My other alternative would be to ditch the @ formatting, use the 'normal' MsgBox without bold and manually add newlines.

Again note, we're calling MsgBox within the Eval statement, to get the formatted dialog.

Comment: Hard to find any documentation about that `Eval` (evil??) trick at all, but it seems you're out of luck and there simply is no escape character. If I where you, I would create a simple form that simulates the message box.

Comment: You might be able to wrist my [ModernBox](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ModernBox) to accept _Access "Rich Text"_, which is HTML formatted text.

Answer (score -1):

Well, that "bold" trick is a separate issue from displaying an address.

You can break a line by using `vbCRLF` in the text.

So, say this VBA code:

```
Dim strAddress      As String

strAddress = "First line of Address" & vbCrLf & _
             "Second line of Address" & vbCrLf & _
             "Third line of Address"
             

MsgBox strAddress, vbInformation, "User Address"
```

And the result is this:

[image]

And the width will increase for you, so, say this:

```
strAddress = "One Microsoft Way" & vbCrLf & _
             "Redmond, WA  98052-6399" & vbCrLf & _
             "Phone:   425.555.0100"
```

And thus we see this:

[image]

However, if you want bold, and formatting...

Why not build your own dialog box? (and it is not clear why you have not already).

It should not take much more time than to build this post, but if some additional formatting beyond line breaks is required, then roll your own form.

A custom dialog form in place of above looks like this:

[image]

In above the first line is bold, but the following lines are not.

Your best bet and road here is to create your own form in place of the message box.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. The question is about a syntax clash between the syntax of `Eval` and the syntax of an email address. The OP is not even trying to display a postal address. They are trying to display an email address.

Comment: Right, and my 2nd suggestion is to build a custom form -  not use the msgbox., which of course solves this issue.